# Can't access volley answer saved

Tags: android, android-studio, android-volley

I am using this method to access a post Volley request

```
...
responseVolley = "";
getProductFromDataBase("6130127000035");
Log.d("responseVolley", responseVolley);
...
```

And my `getProductFromDataBase` is looking like this

```
public void getProductFromDataBase(final String bareCode) {

    mPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    this.mEditor = mPreferences.edit();

    String url = Constants.URL_SELECT_PRODUCT + "?" + Constants.PARAM_PRODUCT_CODE_BARE + bareCode;
    Log.d("URL", url);
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d("response", response);
            responseVolley = response;               

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.d("response", "EROOR");
        }
    }) {
        protected HashMap<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            return (HashMap<String, String>) params;
        }
    };

    RequestHandler.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
}
```

When I am trying to show `responseVolley` it doesn't even show something in the Logcat ( I've tried many other solutions like shared preferences ) but nothing worked

Am I doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Using Volley, you should verify these points :

- Check and recheck the `url` string, if you did not deploy your web app, you should use the IP address you used start your server (http://loaclhost:port_number for example).
- If your web app is not deployed on the internet yet, your server and your android app must be in the same network (try to make a hotspot from your PC and connect from your device).
- In order to see a result in your response, you should return a string for example from the function that route the asked url, i.e. you should have a function in your web app that you want to send data to a function that catch your url in demande, you should return a string in that function.
- You should also verify the error log, use a different tag from the response log tag.
- Some times you should give some retry time (in case of weak connection):

```
stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new RetryPolicy() {
                    @Override
                    public int getCurrentTimeout() {
                        return 50000;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public int getCurrentRetryCount() {
                        return 50000;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void retry(VolleyError error) throws VolleyError {

                    }
                }
```

---

**PS**: In the code you provided you are sending nothing, you should put strings you want to send like this:

```
protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("key", "value");
            return params;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use callback method to do what you expect. With help of an interface, you can achieve what you actually want. If it doesn't work, let me know.

```
getProductFromDataBase("6130127000035");
OnResult onResult = new OnResult() {
       @override
       public void result(String responseVolley) {
        Log.d("responseVolley", responseVolley);
       }
};
```

Your `getProductFromDataBase()` method

```
interface OnResult {
    void result(String responseVolley);
}
public void getProductFromDataBase(final String bareCode) {

    mPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    this.mEditor = mPreferences.edit();

    String url = Constants.URL_SELECT_PRODUCT + "?" + Constants.PARAM_PRODUCT_CODE_BARE + bareCode;
    Log.d("URL", url);
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d("response", response);
            onResult.result(response);               

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.d("response", "EROOR");
        }
    }) {
        protected HashMap<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            return (HashMap<String, String>) params;
        }
    };

    RequestHandler.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
}
```